# Resolve the font "really" used for rendering in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

As explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189010%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) the default `FontFamily` used in Silverlight is *"Portable User Interface"* which resolves to one of the supported local fonts depending on the platform and availability of local fonts.

Is there any way to determine which one is actually used?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant, framework only resolve fonts under hood. But, you can embed/pack fonts in your XAP (silverlight application) with this method you can sure the used font face.

e.g. On Expression Blend 4 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294629(v=expression.40).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Some info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Quote:

> The default value for a referenced FontFamily is initialized with the value Portable User Interface. For non-East Asian cultures, this value is an alias for the font family value (shown here as a string) of "Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande". Lucida Grande and Lucida Sans Unicode in turn are aliases for the same font and are specified as a pair for compatibility reasons.